# Cannot deploy contract in remix with my Metamask

Tags: parity, remix, metamask

I'm following a token contract tutorial on Youtube and everytime I try to deploy the contract on the Kovan testnet (in the remix solidity editor), it sends it off but then fails later. I have sufficient KETH, wo why would this be? Would switching to Parity fix this problem, and what is the difference between Parity and Metamask? Sorry for the long question.

Comment: Does Metamask support Kovan? Could you clarify how your deployment fails?

Comment: @5chdn meta mask has the 'Kovan Testnet' and I could receive KETH without a problem. How the deployment fails is that it is sent to the block chain but I cannot view it on the kovan ether scan and then later it says rejected or cancelled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metamask uses INFURA ( https://infura.io/ ) as a backend. INFURA runs both Geth and Parity clients (for Kovan it's Parity).

We've been having some issues with Kovan recently. The peering has been bad, and our Kovan Parity clients sometimes only have 2 or 3 peers (around last Friday was the worst for some reason). This could affect the ability of transactions to move through the network and get mined. Also, running Parity 1.6.7 (then the most recent version) was even more problematic, so we had to switch back to 1.6.6 . The service should work be working better now, but some of these things are out of our control.